# React Native Firebase Authentication Error

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to create the login user account system and for some reason it is recognizing incorrect passwords after navigating to the home screen instead of before.  (The code I am referring to is the the login() function).  I put console log statements to determine this and 'console.log(errorCode);' is the last thing that is outputted.  Can someone please explain the logic of the code I have written and why incorrect passwords are only recognized at the end? 
The order of console output is 
"Logging in"
"Navigate to Home"
"Login finish"
"auth/wrong-password?
Thanks so much.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  TouchableHighlight,
  TouchableOpacity,
  TextInput,
  KeyboardAvoidingView
} from 'react-native';
import Input from './Input';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';
import {firebaseApp} from './App';
import {Tabs} from './Router';
import {StackNavigator, TabNavigator} from 'react-navigation';
import { Root } from './Router';

export default class LoginScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      email: '',
      password: '',
      status: '',
      success: ''
    }

    this.login = this.login.bind(this);

  }

  login(){
    console.log("Logging in");
    var errorCode;
    var errorMessage;
    firebaseApp.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password).catch(function(error) {
        errorCode = error.code;
        console.log(errorCode);
        errorMessage = error.message;
    });

      if (errorCode === 'auth/wrong-password') {
        console.log("Wrong password");
        alert('Wrong password.');
      } else {
        console.log("Navigate to Home");
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Home');
      }

      //console.log(error);
      console.log("Login finish");


    /*firebaseApp.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password).catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error.code);
      console.log(error.message);
    })

    this.props.navigation.navigate('Home');

    console.log("Navigate to Home");*/
  }

  render() {
    var styles = require('./Styles');
    const {navigate} = this.props.navigation;

    return(
      <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior='padding' style={styles.loginContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.loginHeader}>PRINCETON EVENTS</Text>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.loginInput}
          placeholder="Email"
          autoCapitalize='none'
          onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({email: text})}
          value={this.state.email}
          returnKeyType='next'/>
        <TextInput
          secureTextEntry
          style={styles.loginInput} placeholder="Password"
          onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({password: text})}
          value={this.state.password}
          autoCapitalize='none'
          returnKeyType='go'/>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.loginButton}>
          <Text style={styles.loginText} onPress={this.login}>LOGIN</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.loginButton}
          onPress = {() => navigate('CreateAccount')}>
          <Text style={styles.loginText}> CREATE ACCOUNT </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    );

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need handle success/error cases in then and catch blocks.

```
firebaseApp.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password)
.then(function() { //Auth is successful
   this.props.navigation.navigate('Home');
}
.catch(function(error) {
    errorCode = error.code;
    errorMessage = error.message;
  if (errorCode === 'auth/wrong-password') {
    console.log("Wrong password");
    alert('Wrong password.');
  } else {
    console.log("Navigate to Home");
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Home');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but for the next ones, check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/63958584/9300663

Still working : 13/01/2021.

And for your case, you can use substr() to get rid off 'auth/' from your errorCode.

Something like that :

```
switch (errorCode.substr(5)) {
    case 'ERROR_EMAIL_ALREADY_IN_USE':
    case 'account-exists-with-different-credential':
    case 'email-already-in-use':
      return 'Email already used. Go to login page.';
    case 'ERROR_WRONG_PASSWORD':
    case 'wrong-password':
      return 'Wrong email/password combination.';
    case 'ERROR_USER_NOT_FOUND':
    case 'user-not-found':
      return 'No user found with this email.';
    case 'ERROR_USER_DISABLED':
    case 'user-disabled':
      return 'User disabled.';
    case 'ERROR_TOO_MANY_REQUESTS':
    case 'operation-not-allowed':
      return 'Too many requests to log into this account.';
    case 'ERROR_OPERATION_NOT_ALLOWED':
    case 'operation-not-allowed':
      return 'Server error, please try again later.';
    case 'ERROR_INVALID_EMAIL':
    case 'invalid-email':
      return 'Email address is invalid.';
    default:
      return 'Login failed. Please try again.';
  }
```