# How to Handle Firebase Auth exceptions on flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

Please does anyone know how to catch firebase Auth exceptions on flutter and display them?

Note: I am not interested in the console (catcherror((e) print(e))

I need something that is more effective, e.g " user doesn't exist" So that I can then pass it to a string and display it.

Been dealing with this for months.

Thanks in advance.

I have tried replacing print(e) with // errorMessage=e.toString(); and then passing it to a function, all efforts have been futile.

```
    FirebaseAuth.instance
              .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: emailController.text, password: passwordController.text)
              .then((FirebaseUser user) {
                _isInAsyncCall=false;
            Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed("/TheNextPage");

          }).catchError((e) {
           // errorMessage=e.toString();
            print(e);
            _showDialog(errorMessage);

            //exceptionNotice();
            //print(e);
```

I want to be able to extract the exception message and pass the exception message to a dialog that I can then display to the user.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**(21/02/20) EDIT: This answer is old and the other answers contains cross platform solutions so you should look at theirs first and treat this as a fallback solution.**

The firebase auth plugin doesn't really have a proper cross-platform error code system yet so you have to handle errors for android and ios independently.

I'm currently using the temporary fix from this github issue: [#20223](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/20223#issue-347613208)

Do note since its a ***temp*** fix, don't expect it to be fully reliable as a permanent solution.

```
enum authProblems { UserNotFound, PasswordNotValid, NetworkError }

try {
  FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: email,
      password: password,
  );
} catch (e) {
  authProblems errorType;
  if (Platform.isAndroid) {
    switch (e.message) {
      case 'There is no user record corresponding to this identifier. The user may have been deleted.':
        errorType = authProblems.UserNotFound;
        break;
      case 'The password is invalid or the user does not have a password.':
        errorType = authProblems.PasswordNotValid;
        break;
      case 'A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred.':
        errorType = authProblems.NetworkError;
        break;
      // ...
      default:
        print('Case ${e.message} is not yet implemented');
    }
  } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
    switch (e.code) {
      case 'Error 17011':
        errorType = authProblems.UserNotFound;
        break;
      case 'Error 17009':
        errorType = authProblems.PasswordNotValid;
        break;
      case 'Error 17020':
        errorType = authProblems.NetworkError;
        break;
      // ...
      default:
        print('Case ${e.message} is not yet implemented');
    }
  }
  print('The error is $errorType');
}
```

Comment: This is the error handling portion in a try catch for the firebase auth sign in code

Comment: errors gone, but it still breaks(freeze) when i enter a wrong email address

Comment: Its probably your own code or you are implementing it wrongly. I don't think a try catch like that will freeze your app

Answer (score 46):

**NEW ANSWER (18/09/2020)**

If you are using `firebase_auth: ^0.18.0`, error codes have changed!

For instance: `ERROR_USER_NOT_FOUND` is now `user-not-found`

I could not find any documentation about that, so I went into the source code and read comments for every error codes. *(firebase_auth.dart)*

I don't use all error codes in my app (e.g verification, password reset...) but you will find the most common ones in this code snippet:

**(It handles old and new error codes)**

```
String getMessageFromErrorCode() {
    switch (this.errorCode) {
      case "ERROR_EMAIL_ALREADY_IN_USE":
      case "account-exists-with-different-credential":
      case "email-already-in-use":
        return "Email already used. Go to login page.";
        break;
      case "ERROR_WRONG_PASSWORD":
      case "wrong-password":
        return "Wrong email/password combination.";
        break;
      case "ERROR_USER_NOT_FOUND":
      case "user-not-found":
        return "No user found with this email.";
        break;
      case "ERROR_USER_DISABLED":
      case "user-disabled":
        return "User disabled.";
        break;
      case "ERROR_TOO_MANY_REQUESTS":
      case "operation-not-allowed":
        return "Too many requests to log into this account.";
        break;
      case "ERROR_OPERATION_NOT_ALLOWED":
      case "operation-not-allowed":
        return "Server error, please try again later.";
        break;
      case "ERROR_INVALID_EMAIL":
      case "invalid-email":
        return "Email address is invalid.";
        break;
      default:
        return "Login failed. Please try again.";
        break;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, very useful! But, I think, `ERROR_EMAIL_ALREADY_IN_USE` == `email-already-in-use`

Comment: @IvanPavliuk You are right, I forgot to edit my post. Both `account-exists-with-different-credential` and `email-already-in-use` work. Thanks!

Comment: int the latest firebase_auth version to get the error code it will be this.code instead of this.errorcode...other than this it works perfectly

Comment: @Emam It is a custom class I made with a custom errorCode attribute. Glad it works!

Answer (score 43):

**If you are using firebase_auth: ^0.18.0, error codes have changed! Check the next answer.**

I just coded myself a way to do this without Platform dependent Code:

This is possible since .signInWithEmailAndPassword correctly throws Errors with defined codes, that we can grab to identify the error and handle things in the way the should be handled.

The following example creates a new Future.error, if any error happens, and a Bloc is then configured to shovel that data through to the Widget.

```
Future<String> signIn(String email, String password) async {
  FirebaseUser user;
  String errorMessage;
  
  try {
    AuthResult result = await _firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
    user = result.user;
  } catch (error) {
    switch (error.code) {
      case "ERROR_INVALID_EMAIL":
        errorMessage = "Your email address appears to be malformed.";
        break;
      case "ERROR_WRONG_PASSWORD":
        errorMessage = "Your password is wrong.";
        break;
      case "ERROR_USER_NOT_FOUND":
        errorMessage = "User with this email doesn't exist.";
        break;
      case "ERROR_USER_DISABLED":
        errorMessage = "User with this email has been disabled.";
        break;
      case "ERROR_TOO_MANY_REQUESTS":
        errorMessage = "Too many requests. Try again later.";
        break;
      case "ERROR_OPERATION_NOT_ALLOWED":
        errorMessage = "Signing in with Email and Password is not enabled.";
        break;
      default:
        errorMessage = "An undefined Error happened.";
    }
  }

  if (errorMessage != null) {
    return Future.error(errorMessage);
  }

  return user.uid;
}
```

Comment: The only issue I see with this answer is that the "error" in the catch doesnt always contains a "code", meaning that your code will break with "Uncaught TypeError: e.get$code is not a functionError: TypeError: e.get$code is not a function"

So you have to use an explicit catch, something like:
"on PlatformException catch(e)" and then you will be sure that it does contains a code that you can hande with that switch in this answer.

Additional note: You will also need to include "import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show PlatformException;" in your imports.

Comment: have you tested that ? in my experience a error.code resulting in null would call the "default" of the switch block.

Comment: I think @Frank s remark applies to the dart2js version.
There does not seem to be an easy way to check if error has the getter `code`.
But you could use a helper like this:

https://gist.github.com/ltOgt/04212037dca1d7a68b4e89dddc750bbd

Comment: Here is a valid list of error codes: https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseAuth/signInWithEmailAndPassword.html

Comment: These error messages are outdated. See @corentinhoudayer's answer.

Comment: use ```on FirebaseAuthException catch (e)``` instead of ```catch (e)```, the ```code``` will be solved, it works for me, hope will works for you.

Answer (score 10):

Expanding on the accepted answer I thought it's worth to mention that:

1. The `firebase_auth` plugin has **AuthException**.
2. As pointed out in this [Github issue post](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/20223#issuecomment-515888763) you can have the same error codes for Android and iOS.
3. If you have this code in a non-UI layer you can use `rethrow` or better throw your own formatted exceptions and catch those at the UI level (where you'll know exactly the kind of error you'll get).

---

```
try {
  AuthResult authResult = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);
  // Your auth logic ...
} on AuthException catch (e) {
  print('''
    caught firebase auth exception\n
    ${e.code}\n
    ${e.message}
  ''');

  var message = 'Oops!'; // Default message
  switch (e.code) {
    case 'ERROR_WRONG_PASSWORD':
      message = 'The password you entered is totally wrong!';
      break;
    // More custom messages ...
  }
  throw Exception(message); // Or extend this with a custom exception class
} catch (e) {
  print('''
    caught exception\n
    $e
  ''');
  rethrow;
}
```

Comment: There is also PlatformException for Firebase specific errors like ERROR_ACCOUNT_EXISTS_WITH_DIFFERENT_CREDENTIAL

Answer (score 8):

in Auth Class have this function:

```
Future signUpWithEmailAndPassword(String email, String password) async {
    try {
      AuthResult result = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: email,
        password: password,
      );
      FirebaseUser user = result.user;
      return user;
    } catch (e) {
      return e;
    }
  }
```

The catch error above returns a runTimeType of PlatformException and a PlatformException in flutter has 3 properties check [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/PlatformException-class.html)!

---

in your Dart file, implement this on button listeners:

```
String error = "";

dynamic result = await _auth.signUpWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);

if (result.runtimeType == PlatformException) {
    if (result.message != null) {
        setState(() {
            error = result.message;
        });
    } else {
        setState(() {
            error = "Unknown Error";
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I manage the firebase auth exception with the exceptions codes of the version

```
firebase_auth: ^3.3.6
firebase_core: ^1.12.0
```

This is the code that work for me:

```
Future<void> loginWithEmailAndPassword({
required String email,
required String password,
}) async {
try {
  await _firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: email, password: password);
} on firebase_auth.FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
  switch (e.code) {
    case "invalid-email":
      //Thrown if the email address is not valid.
      throw InvalidEmailException();
    case "user-disabled":
      //Thrown if the user corresponding to the given email has been disabled.
      throw UserDisabledException();
    case "user-not-found":
      //Thrown if there is no user corresponding to the given email.
      throw UserNotFoundException();
    case "wrong-password":
      throw PasswordExceptions();
    //Thrown if the password is invalid for the given email, or the account corresponding to the email does not have a password set.
    default:
      throw UncknownAuthException();
  }
 }
}
```

And I create the exceptions to control the messeges to display in the UI later like this:

```
class AuthenticationException implements Exception {}
class InvalidEmailException extends AuthenticationException {}
class PasswordExceptions extends AuthenticationException {}
class UserNotFoundException extends AuthenticationException {}
class UserDisabledException extends AuthenticationException {}
class UncknownAuthException extends AuthenticationException {}
```

Hope it help to someone having problems to handle auth exceptions!

Answer (score 7):

the exceptions can be handled using, FirebaseAuthException class.

Here's the code for login using email and password:

```
void loginUser(String email, String password) async {
    try {
      await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password:password);
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      // Your logic for Firebase related exceptions
    } catch (e) {
    // your logic for other exceptions!
}
```

You can use your own logic to handle the error, e.g show a alert dialog, etc.
Same can be done for creating a user.

Answer (score 6):

So I faced this issue today and instead of hardcoding the error messages to display, I decided to use string manipulations and I managed to get the message.

The goal was to get the message (everything after `]`).
Example: get this => **Password should be at least 6 characters** from this => **[firebase_auth/weak-password] Password should be at least 6 characters**.

So using the exception from the try-catch, I converted it to string first, then replaced the first 14 characters (from '[' to '/') with nothing, so I was left with **weak-password] Password should be at least 6 characters**.

Then the split function with ']' pattern to search the remaining string for the ']' symbol and split the whole string into two with the index of the ']' symbol as the pivot. This returns a list with two Strings; **'weak-password'** and **'Password should be at least 6 characters'**. Use the index 1 to get the second string which is the error message.

```
e.toString().replaceRange(0, 14, '').split(']')[1]
```

Comment: This works perfectly.  Just to extend incase its not a firebaseAuth error I have `if (e.runtimetype == FirebaseAuthException) String mssge = Quwaysims answer else string mssege = error logging in please try again`

Answer (score 4):

in Dart you can react to different Exceptions using the `on` syntax. Since Firebase uses its own PlatformException you can easily catch them with:

```
  try {
      AuthResult result = await signUp(email, password);
  } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      print(e.message);
  } on Exception catch (e) {
      print(e);
  }
```

PlatformException brings a code as well as a message which can be displayed in the UI, i.e. :

```
PlatformException(ERROR_EMAIL_ALREADY_IN_USE, The email address is already in use by another account., null)
```

Answer (score 3):

I was stuck on this for a while too, i created this gist with all the available errors [here](https://gist.github.com/nikhilmufc7/6b74a3c12a6e2d3284942d40ff583e37) with an example, covers all the platform exception codes

Example for handling sign up exceptions

```
Future<String> signUp(String email, String password, String firstName) async {
  FirebaseUser user;

  try {
    AuthResult result = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: email, password: password);
    user = result.user;
    name = user.displayName;
    email = user.email;

    Firestore.instance.collection('users').document(user.uid).setData({
      "uid": user.uid,
      "firstName": firstName,
      "email": email,
      "userImage": userImage,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    switch (error.code) {
      case "ERROR_OPERATION_NOT_ALLOWED":
        errorMessage = "Anonymous accounts are not enabled";
        break;
      case "ERROR_WEAK_PASSWORD":
        errorMessage = "Your password is too weak";
        break;
      case "ERROR_INVALID_EMAIL":
        errorMessage = "Your email is invalid";
        break;
      case "ERROR_EMAIL_ALREADY_IN_USE":
        errorMessage = "Email is already in use on different account";
        break;
      case "ERROR_INVALID_CREDENTIAL":
        errorMessage = "Your email is invalid";
        break;

      default:
        errorMessage = "An undefined Error happened.";
    }
  }
  if (errorMessage != null) {
    return Future.error(errorMessage);
  }

  return user.uid;
}
```

Example for handling sign in exceptions

```
Future<String> signIn(String email, String password) async {
  FirebaseUser user;
  try {
    AuthResult result = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: email, password: password);
    user = result.user;
    name = user.displayName;
    email = user.email;
    userId = user.uid;
  } catch (error) {
    switch (error.code) {
      case "ERROR_INVALID_EMAIL":
        errorMessage = "Your email address appears to be malformed.";
        break;
      case "ERROR_WRONG_PASSWORD":
        errorMessage = "Your password is wrong.";
        break;
      case "ERROR_USER_NOT_FOUND":
        errorMessage = "User with this email doesn't exist.";
        break;
      case "ERROR_USER_DISABLED":
        errorMessage = "User with this email has been disabled.";
        break;
      case "ERROR_TOO_MANY_REQUESTS":
        errorMessage = "Too many requests. Try again later.";
        break;
      case "ERROR_OPERATION_NOT_ALLOWED":
        errorMessage = "Signing in with Email and Password is not enabled.";
        break;
      default:
        errorMessage = "An undefined Error happened.";
    }
  }
  if (errorMessage != null) {
    return Future.error(errorMessage);
  }

  return user.uid;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to create api layer response and error models and wrap the firebase plugin error and response objects in them. For sign in with email and password i have this

```
@override
  Future<dynamic> loginWithEmailAndPassword(String email, String password) async {
    try {
      await _firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: password);
      return FirebaseSignInWithEmailResponse();
    } catch (exception) {
      return _mapLoginWithEmailError(exception);
    }
  }

  ApiError _mapLoginWithEmailError(PlatformException error) {
    final code = error.code;
    if (code == 'ERROR_INVALID_EMAIL') {
      return FirebaseSignInWithEmailError(
          message: 'Your email is not valid. Please enter a valid email',
          type: FirebaseSignInWithEmailErrorType.INVALID_EMAIL);
    } else if (code == 'ERROR_WRONG_PASSWORD') {
      return FirebaseSignInWithEmailError(
          message: 'Your password is incorrect',
          type: FirebaseSignInWithEmailErrorType.WRONG_PASSWORD);
    } else if (code == 'ERROR_USER_NOT_FOUND') {
      return FirebaseSignInWithEmailError(
          message: 'You do not have an account. Please Sign Up to'
              'proceed',
          type: FirebaseSignInWithEmailErrorType.USER_NOT_FOUND);
    } else if (code == 'ERROR_TOO_MANY_REQUESTS') {
      return FirebaseSignInWithEmailError(
          message: 'Did you forget your credentials? Reset your password',
          type: FirebaseSignInWithEmailErrorType.TOO_MANY_REQUESTS);
    } else if (code == 'ERROR_USER_DISABLED') {
      return FirebaseSignInWithEmailError(
          message: 'Your account has been disabled. Please contact support',
          type: FirebaseSignInWithEmailErrorType.USER_DISABLED);
    } else if (code == 'ERROR_OPERATION_NOT_ALLOWED') {
      throw 'Email and Password accounts are disabled. Enable them in the '
          'firebase console?';
    } else {
      return FirebaseSignInWithEmailError(
          message: 'Make sure you have a stable connection and try again'
          type: FirebaseSignInWithEmailErrorType.CONNECTIVITY);
    }
  }
```

I never return the `AuthResult` from firebase. Instead i listen to the `onAuthStateChanged` stream and react accordingly if there is a change.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same error of "firebse platform exeption:" in flutter using "Firebase auth"
and it didn't resolve even using try catch and trim() method in passing arrguments.

The problem is when you run app using Button "Run" in main.dart it won't callback and catch the error.

Solution: In Vscode terminal type "Flutter run" (for debug mode). or "Flutter run --release" (for release mode) now you won't face platform exception.

Answer (score 1):

I had an issue where I didn't want the "com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occurred. [ Unable to resolve host "www.googleapis.com":No address associated
with hostname ]" which would indicate to a user that the backend being used is firebase. Thus, I just used toString().replaceAll()

```
  Future<void> signIn() async {
final formState = _formkey.currentState;
var _date = DateTime.now();

if (formState!.validate()) {
  emailFocus!.unfocus();
  passwordFocus!.unfocus();
  formState.save();
  setState(() {
    isloading = true;
    _errorMessage = '';
  });
  try {
    UserCredential user = await _firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: _email, password: _password!);

    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setString('email', _email);

    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('Users Token Data')
        .doc(user.user!.uid)
        .set({'Email': _email, 'Token': _token, 'Date': _date});

    Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
        context, RouteNames.homePage, (e) => false);
  } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
    setState(() {
      isloading = false;
      _errorMessage = e.message.toString().replaceAll(
          'com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has' +
              ' occurred. [ Unable to resolve host "www.googleapis.com":' +
              "No address associated with hostname ]",
          "Please Check Network Connection");
    });
    print(e.message);
  }
}
```

}
}

Just incase if you don't wanna reveal too much information from the error message.

Answer (score 0):

I have also recently faced this error and, I have found out that the `.catchError()` callback wasn't being called in the debug mode (which is when you click the `Run->Start Debugging` button in VSCode).

However, when you type in flutter run -d , then, the `.catchError()` method gets called back as it is not in debug mode.

To get your preferred simulator's code paste this line of code in the terminal:

```
instruments -s devices
```

If that doesn't work, you can also try pasting this:

```
xcrun simctl list
```

The  ```.catchError()`` method will get called unlike before and the code inside that will get executed as expected!

Additionally, the app won't crash anymore with a `PlatformException()` and instead you will get a log like this one:

```
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'uid' was called on null.
Receiver: null
```

I have been facing this problem in Google Sign In too, in which the `.catchError()` was not being called!

In conclusion, if you have some error with handling errors in Firebase Authentication, you should first try to first run in through the terminal. Thanks, and I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

try this , i had the same proplem and this code worked with me

```
catch (e) {
                        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
                            .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text('Wrong UserName or Password')));
                      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Firebase-Auth Latest version provides a simple way to get error code and error Messages using the following try catch statements:

```
try {
  await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
    email: "name@example.com",
    password: "SuperSecretPassword!"
  );
} on FirebaseAuthException catch  (e) {
  print('Failed with error code: ${e.code}');
  print(e.message);
}
```

Source:
[Firebase Documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/error-handling/)

Answer (score 0):

This code will show a red snack bar that contains the exception cause like "User already in use by other account".

```dart
auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
   email: email,
   password: password,
).onError((error,stackTrace){
   if(error.runtimeType == FirebaseAuthException) {
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
     SnackBar(
      content: Text(error.toString().replaceRange(0, 14, '').split(']')[1]),
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.error,
     ),
   );
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
   try {
  final newuser = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: emailController.text, password: passwordController.text);
  // print("Done");
} catch (e) {
  print(e);
  showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return AlertDialog(
        title: new Text(e.message),
        actions: <Widget>[
          FlatButton(
            child: new Text("OK"),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
          ),
        ],
      );
    },
  );
}
```

Comment: since this is an old question, consider adding some explanation how this works and why this is better.