# how to display an error message if email and password is not valid in firebase flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

i have developed an login page,if the email and password matches from the database it successfully login's and moves to the new page,but if its wrong i want to display an error message email or password doesn't match.

Here's my code:

```
class _AdminLoginState extends State<AdminLogin> {
  String _username, _password;
  TextEditingController _email = TextEditingController();


  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formkey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('LOGIN'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.indigo[900],


      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 50),
              child: SizedBox(
                height: 150.0,
                width: 300,
                child: Image.asset("assets/admin.png",
                  fit: BoxFit.contain,),


              ),
            ),
            Container(

              child: Text("ADMIN",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,color: Colors.indigo),),

            ),
            Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 50),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  SingleChildScrollView(

                    child: Form(
                      key: _formkey,
                      child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 60,
                          ),

                          SizedBox(
                            width: 380,
                            height: 70,
                            child: Container(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(4),
                              width: 500,
                              height: 60,
                              child: TextFormField(
                                autofocus: false,
                                obscureText: false,
                                keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                                validator:(input){
                                  if(input.isEmpty){
                                    return 'please type username';
                                  }
                                  return null;
                                },
                                onSaved: (input) => _username =input ,
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    labelText: 'Email',
                                    hintText: "Email",
                                    labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                      fontSize: 16,
                                    ),
                                  border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(

                                      const Radius.circular(20.0),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),


                              ),
                            ),
                          ),

                          SizedBox(
                            width: 380,
                            height: 70,
                            child: Container(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(4),
                              width: 400,
                              height: 60,
                              child: TextFormField(
                                autofocus: false,
                                obscureText: true,
                                validator:(input){
                                  if(input.isEmpty){
                                    return 'please type Password';
                                  }
                                  return null;
                                },
                                onSaved: (input) => _password =input ,
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    labelText: 'Password',
                                    hintText: "Password",
                                    labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                      fontSize: 16,
                                    ),
                                  border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                                      const Radius.circular(20.0),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),


                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(4),
                            width: 500,
                            height: 60,
                            child: RaisedButton(
                              onPressed: login,
                              textColor: Colors.white,
                              color: Colors.indigo[900],
                              child: Text('Login'),
                            ),
                          )


                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),


                ],


              ),
            ),

          ],

        ),
      ),
      );

  }
  Future<void> login() async{
    final  formState = _formkey.currentState;
    if(formState.validate()){
      formState.save();
      try{

        final FirebaseUser user = (await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: _username, password: _password)).user;
        Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Admin()));
      }catch(e){
        print(e.message);
      }


    }
  }
}
```

it will be really helpful if someone also helps me in validating the right email format and give give the proper validation for password

Answer (score 0):

signInWithEmailAndPassword() returns an exception with a special code if the attempt is unsuccessful.

In order to print a message you need to add a catch block to your signInWithEmailAndPassword() method. Then you can use the error message.

Example:

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .catch(function(error) {
  // Handle Errors here.
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
  if (errorCode === 'auth/wrong-password') {
    alert('Wrong password.');
  } else {
    alert(errorMessage);
  }
  console.log(error);
});
```

For security purposes I would suggest combining some of the messages together instead of giving a possible attacker a hint about if the email is already in the system or not.

I do not know how to use flutter so I can only give an idea;

In here you are directly trying to get the user from the method.

```
final FirebaseUser user = (await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: _username, password: _password)).user;
```

Instead I would suggest using something like this (this is angular but I think you can easily apply to flutter with some modification)

```
final FirebaseUser user;

 await firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then((data) => {
          this.user = data.user;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        switch (error.code) {
          case "auth/invalid-email":
          case "auth/wrong-password":
          case "auth/user-not-found":
            {
              this.accountErrorMessage = "Wrong email address or password.";
              break;
            }
          case "auth/user-disabled":
          case "user-disabled":
            {
              this.accountErrorMessage = "This account is disabled";
              break;
            }
        }
```

You can find which kind of errors it may return from here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth.html#signinwithemailandpassword

Comment: can you suggest me how can i use this set lines in my code please

Comment: should i replace these entire lines with that single line?

Comment: that code firebase.auth() i'm not able to include in my codes its throwing an exception

Comment: it's angular code, you need to change it for your language `FirebaseAuth.instance.` probably

Comment: i'm seriously new to flutter can you help me in it i don't know how to do it\

Comment: you can try simplifying with directly displaying the error message instead of using switch statement.

Comment: I think this may help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56113778/how-to-handle-firebase-auth-exceptions-on-flutter

Answer (score 0):

Use `errortext` in `InputDecoration`

here is demo

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Demo'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[

            TextField(
              controller: _text,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'email',
                errorText: loginfail ? 'email not match' : null,
              ),
            ),
            TextField(
              controller: _text,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'password',
                errorText: loginfail ? 'password not match' : null,
              ),
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                login();
              },
              child: Text('Submit'),
              textColor: Colors.white,
              color: Colors.blueAccent,
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

Future<void> login() async{
    final  formState = _formkey.currentState;
    if(formState.validate()){
      formState.save();
      try{

        final FirebaseUser user = (await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: _username, password: _password)).user;
        if(!user.uid.isEmpty()){
         Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Admin()));
        }else{
         setState((){
           loginfail = true; //loginfail is bool
          });
        }

      }catch(e){
        print(e.message);
      }
    }
```

hope it helps..

Comment: should i declare loginfail as false in the beginnig

Comment: this way, you are not going to know what is the reason for the fail and it will show the error for both of the fields. Two errors may confuse users because even if just the password is wrong, error says email is wrong as well.

Comment: debug what you get in `user` var

Comment: can you tell me how to do that?

Comment: rohit bhai just add `print(user);`

Comment: W/BiChannelGoogleApi(17122): [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzak@553c36e
I/flutter (17122): The email address is badly formatted.

Comment: chek i edit my answer, chek `if(!user.uid.isEmpty())` is not empty

Answer (score 0):

Following @Jaydeepchatrola answer's

I used a try catch block and checked if password was invalid or email, for better results!

```
               try {
                    setState(() {
                      wrongEmail = false;
                      wrongPassword = false;
                    });
                    final newUser = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                        email: email, password: password);
                    if (newUser != null) {
                      Navigator.pushNamed(context, Done.id);
                    }
                  } catch (e) {
                    print(e.code);
                    if (e.code == 'ERROR_WRONG_PASSWORD') {
                      setState(() {
                        wrongPassword = true;
                      });
                    } else {
                      setState(() {
                        emailText = 'User doesn\'t exist';
                        passwordText = 'Please check your email';

                        wrongPassword = true;
                        wrongEmail = true;
                      });
                    }
                  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to catch the specific error. I had the problem by myself, with this code I solved the problem.

```
try {
        final user = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
            email: email, password: password);
        if (user != null) {
          Navigator.pushNamed(context, HomeScreen.id);
        }
      } on auth.FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
     //Here you catch the specific error 
        if (e.code == 'wrong-password') {
    //The thing that should happen if the password is incorrect
   //In my case it will the change the hinttext  
          setState(() {
            hintTextPassword = 'Password incorrect. Please try again';
            passwordHintColor = Colors.red;
          });
        } else if (e.code == 'user-not-found') {
          setState(() {
            hintTextEmail = 'No user found for that email.';
            emailHintColor = Colors.red;
          });
        }
      } catch (e) {
        print(e);
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. add rflutter_alert: ^2.0.4  in your project file pubspec.yaml under dependencies: and save it
2. add `import 'package:rflutter_alert/rflutter_alert.dart';` in your file of your auth screen
3. add

   Alert(
   context: context,
   title: "Failed Login",
   desc: "Incorrect Email Or Password.")
   .show();

in catch(e){}

like that:

```
Future<void> login() async{
    final  formState = _formkey.currentState;
    if(formState.validate()){
      formState.save();
      try{

        final FirebaseUser user = (await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: _username, password: _password)).user;
        Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Admin()));
      }catch(e){
        Alert(
                                context: context,
                                title: "Failed Login",
                                desc: "Incorrect Email Or Password.")
                            .show();
      }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This method works.

```
catch (e) {
    String errorMessage = e.toString();
    Get.snackbar(
      'Sign-up Failed',
      errorMessage.substring(errorMessage.indexOf(']') + 1),
      snackPosition: SnackPosition.BOTTOM,
    );
```