# Uncaught Firebase exception

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I have a login and register methods that don't catch the exceptions and I don't know why.

```
  static Future<void> register(BuildContext context,
      {@required String email, @required String password, @required displayName, @required gender}) async {
    try {
      final authResult = await FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);

      if (authResult.user != null) {
        FirestoreInit.initDocs(authResult.user);
        FirestoreInit.initUser(authResult.user, gender, displayName);

        await authResult.user.updateProfile(displayName: displayName);
        await authResult.user.reload();

        Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(Routing.routeName, arguments: authResult.user);
      }
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (exception) {
      signUpFailureDialog(context, exception);
    } on PlatformException catch (exception) {
      signUpFailureDialog(context, exception);
    } catch (uknownError) {
      uknownSignUpFailureDialog(context, uknownError);
    }
  }
```

I get the following exception in vscode:

> Exception has occurred. PlatformException
> (PlatformException(firebase_auth,
> com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException: The email
> address is already in use by another account., {code:
> email-already-in-use, additionalData: {}, message: The email address
> is already in use by another account.}, null))

I can't understand why the catch line on platform exception does not run

```
on PlatformException catch (exception) {
    signUpFailureDialog(context, exception);
}
```

The code for the dialog for completion sake:

```
void signInFailureDialog(BuildContext context, dynamic exception) {
  showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (context) {
      return AlertDialog(
        title: Text(exception.code),
        content: Text(exception.message),
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        shape: ContinuousRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(45)),
      );
    },
  );
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56113778/how-to-handle-firebase-auth-exceptions-on-flutter

Comment: The question linked does not address my issue though. My catch block never executes. The question is asking about how to show the firebase error message. That's not my issue. My issue is that Firebase exceptions are not being caught by the catch block in the first place. The exception crashes the app in the Firebase login and create user methods. At any rate I have tried implementing the answers in the linked question, but since the catch block is not executing, my issue is not resolved.