# Pop-up message on emulator from platform exception in flutter (login verification)

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

When I enter the incorrect password or username, the error only shown in the message_codecs.dart instead of shown on the screen? Is it possible to have a pop-up dialog message to show the error message based on a different condition? I am trying to use a CASE statement in try-catch but it does not work. The database that I used is firebase to verify the user login.

**The output I got from the console.**
I/BiChannelGoogleApi(15982): [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzao@2776809

**The exception I got from the message_codecs.dart**
PlatformException (PlatformException(firebase_auth, com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthInvalidUserException: There is no user record corresponding to this identifier. The user may have been deleted., {code: user-not-found, additionalData: {}, message: There is no user record corresponding to this identifier. The user may have been deleted.}, null))

```
void validateAndSubmit() async {
    if (validateAndSave()) {
      try {
        String userId = _formType == FormType.login
            ? await widget.auth.signIn(_email, _password)
            : await widget.auth.createUser(_email, _password);
        setState(() {
          _authHint = 'Signed In\n\nUser id: $userId';
        });
        widget.onSignIn();
      } on PlatformException catch (e) {
        switch (e.code) {
          case "ERROR_EMAIL_ALREADY_IN_USE":
          case "account-exists-with-different-credential":
          case "email-already-in-use":
           throw StateError("Email already used. Go to login page.");
            break;
          case "ERROR_WRONG_PASSWORD":
          case "wrong-password":
            throw StateError( "Wrong email/password combination.");
            break;
          case "ERROR_USER_NOT_FOUND":
          case "user-not-found":
            throw StateError( "No user found with this email.");
            break;
          case "ERROR_USER_DISABLED":
          case "user-disabled":
            throw StateError("User disabled.");
            break;
          case "ERROR_TOO_MANY_REQUESTS":
          case "operation-not-allowed":
            throw StateError( "Too many requests to log into this account.");
            break;
          case "ERROR_OPERATION_NOT_ALLOWED":
          case "operation-not-allowed":
            throw StateError("Server error, please try again later.");
            break;
          case "ERROR_INVALID_EMAIL":
          case "invalid-email":
            throw StateError("Email address is invalid.");
            break;
          default:
            throw StateError("Login failed. Please try again.");
            break;
        }
```

[image: Exception]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56113778/how-to-handle-firebase-auth-exceptions-on-flutter

Answer (score 0):

You can use `showDialog()` method to show a dialog with the error message:

```
      showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return AlertDialog(
              title: Text("Error"),
              content: Text(err.message),
              actions: [
                FlatButton(
                  child: Text("Ok"),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  },
                )
              ],
            );
          });
```

You don't have to use switch case, because firebase already returns an error message for you. Example if the error code is `ERROR_EMAIL_ALREADY_IN_USE` then the message will be:

> The email address is already in use by another account.

Comment: this does not work for me .... the exception is still shown on the dart, not on the screen.

Comment: In your code is it entering the catch and going to the `stateerror()`?