# Handle Firebase erros Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I didn't understand how to handle errors on Firebase calls, even if I set try and catches my app freezes...For example in the code below I set some try and catch with this idea :
"Try to call this Firebase function, if it works ok otherwise create a window dialogue telling the user that they aren't registered ". But the result is that the call fails and app freezes...

This is the code :

```
Future<void> submit(
      context, FirebaseAuth authF, String email, String password) async {
    try {
      final userCredential = await authF.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: email,
        password: password,
      );
      return;
    } catch (e) {
      if (Platform.isIOS) {
        LogInCupertinoDialogue(context);
      } else {
        LogInAndroidDialogue(context);
      }
      return;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why your app crashes with your code.

However, you might want to know that you can catch Firebase errors using `FirebaseAuthException`  in your case.

Here is an example :

```
try {
  await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
    email: "someemail@email.com",
    password: "password"
  );
} on FirebaseAuthException catch  (e) {
  print('Error code: ${e.code}');
  print(e.message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56113778/how-to-handle-firebase-auth-exceptions-on-flutter)
Here are more solutions to fix your problem

**It's my method for handle firebase auth error:**
First, you need to create an enum for set and get error message within SnackBar or other...

```dart
enum AuthStatus {
  loading,
  successful,
  emailAlreadyExists,
  wrongPassword,
  invalidEmail,
  userNotFound,
  userDisabled,
  operationNotAllowed,
  tooManyRequests,
  undefined,
}
```

And we need a method for handle error is here:

```dart
static handleFireAuthException(e) {
    print(e.code);
    var status;
    switch (e.code) {
      case "invalid-email":
        status = AuthStatus.invalidEmail;
        break;
      case "wrong-password":
        status = AuthStatus.wrongPassword;
        break;
      case "user-not-found":
        status = AuthStatus.userNotFound;
        break;
      case "user-disabled":
        status = AuthStatus.userDisabled;
        break;
      case "too-many-requests":
        status = AuthStatus.tooManyRequests;
        break;
      case "operation-not-allowed":
        status = AuthStatus.operationNotAllowed;
        break;
      case "email-already-in-use":
        status = AuthStatus.emailAlreadyExists;
        break;
      default:
        status = AuthStatus.undefined;
    }
    return status;
  }
```

And the last method is for getting an error message with listening `AuthStatus` so it is errorMessageGenerator:

```dart
 static generateExceptionMessage(exceptionCode) {
    String errorMessage;
    switch (exceptionCode) {
      case AuthStatus.invalidEmail:
        errorMessage = "Your email address appears to be malformed.";
        break;
      case AuthStatus.wrongPassword:
        errorMessage = "Your password is wrong.";
        break;
      case AuthStatus.userNotFound:
        errorMessage = "User with this email doesn't exist.";
        break;
      case AuthStatus.userDisabled:
        errorMessage = "User with this email has been disabled.";
        break;
      case AuthStatus.tooManyRequests:
        errorMessage = "Too many requests. Try again later";
        break;
      case AuthStatus.operationNotAllowed:
        errorMessage = "Message for operation not allowed";
        break;
      case AuthStatus.emailAlreadyExists:
        errorMessage =
            "Already created an account in this Email, if is you, you can try sign in.";
        break;
      default:
        errorMessage = "Signing in with Email and Password is not enabled.";
    }

    return errorMessage;
  }
```

Full code:

```dart
enum AuthStatus {
  loading,
  successful,
  emailAlreadyExists,
  wrongPassword,
  invalidEmail,
  userNotFound,
  userDisabled,
  operationNotAllowed,
  tooManyRequests,
  undefined,
}

class AuthExceptionHandler {
  static handleFireAuthException(e) {
    print(e.code);
    var status;
    switch (e.code) {
      case "invalid-email":
        status = AuthStatus.invalidEmail;
        break;
      case "wrong-password":
        status = AuthStatus.wrongPassword;
        break;
      case "user-not-found":
        status = AuthStatus.userNotFound;
        break;
      case "user-disabled":
        status = AuthStatus.userDisabled;
        break;
      case "too-many-requests":
        status = AuthStatus.tooManyRequests;
        break;
      case "operation-not-allowed":
        status = AuthStatus.operationNotAllowed;
        break;
      case "email-already-in-use":
        status = AuthStatus.emailAlreadyExists;
        break;
      default:
        status = AuthStatus.undefined;
    }
    return status;
  }

  static generateExceptionMessage(exceptionCode) {
    String errorMessage;
    switch (exceptionCode) {
      case AuthStatus.invalidEmail:
        errorMessage = "Your email address appears to be malformed.";
        break;
      case AuthStatus.wrongPassword:
        errorMessage = "Your password is wrong.";
        break;
      case AuthStatus.userNotFound:
        errorMessage = "User with this email doesn't exist.";
        break;
      case AuthStatus.userDisabled:
        errorMessage = "User with this email has been disabled.";
        break;
      case AuthStatus.tooManyRequests:
        errorMessage = "Too many requests. Try again later";
        break;
      case AuthStatus.operationNotAllowed:
        errorMessage = "Message for operation not allowed";
        break;
      case AuthStatus.emailAlreadyExists:
        errorMessage =
            "Already created an account in this Email, if is you, you can try sign in.";
        break;
      default:
        errorMessage = "Signing in with Email and Password is not enabled.";
    }

    return errorMessage;
  }
}
```