# Handle Firebase Auth Errores on Flutter for End Users

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

Everytime i get an error, for example on the login screen: "invalid password", i get a string with a message like:

[image]

How can i change this message to an user friendly one? I tried with the following code that i found on another post:

```
class Errors {
  static String show(String errMsg) {
    switch (errMsg) {
      case 'ERROR_EMAIL_ALREADY_IN_USE':
        return "This e-mail address is already in use, please use a different e-mail address.";

      case 'ERROR_INVALID_EMAIL':
        return "The email address is badly formatted.";

      case 'ERROR_ACCOUNT_EXISTS_WITH_DIFFERENT_CREDENTIAL':
        return "The e-mail address in your Facebook account has been registered in the system before. Please login by trying other methods with this e-mail address.";

      case 'ERROR_WRONG_PASSWORD':
        return "E-mail address or password is incorrect.";

      default:
        return "An error has occurred";
    }
  }
}
```

But it always displays the default error on screen. I tried using "firebase_auth/wrong-password" or "wrong-password" on the cases but did not work. Did anyone have a better solution? I'm new on this!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56113778/how-to-handle-firebase-auth-exceptions-on-flutter I think this is exactly what you are looking for

Comment: I will check it out and try it!

Answer (score 0):

try read this docs here:

https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage

As you can see on the docs, the letter is in small letter and is seperated by "-".

Answer (score 0):

```
I searched a bit on the post from ZOthix and i did find the solution.

I post it here for anyone who needs it:
```

```
class Errors {
  static String show(String errMsg) {
    switch (errMsg) {
      case "email-already-in-use":
        return "Email already used. Go to login page.";
        break;
      case "wrong-password":
        return "Wrong email/password combination.";
        break;
      case "user-not-found":
        return "No user found with this email.";
        break;
      case "user-disabled":
        return "User disabled.";
        break;
      case "ERROR_TOO_MANY_REQUESTS":
      case "operation-not-allowed":
        return "Too many requests to log into this account.";
        break;
      case "ERROR_OPERATION_NOT_ALLOWED":
      case "operation-not-allowed":
        return "Server error, please try again later.";
        break;
      case "invalid-email":
        return "Email address is invalid.";
        break;
      default:
        return "Login failed. Please try again.";
        break;
    }
  }
}
```