# Handle Firebase_Auth errors and show errors on screen

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

I want to handle firebase_auth exceptions and show the error messages on the screen. I have a couple of questions regarding displaying the error messages on the screen.

1. Is there something that displays the messages automatically?
2. or do I need to provide a textfield or label for displaying the message?

I am using the latest package:   firebase_auth: ^3.0.1

Here is my code for logging in:

```
RoundedButton(
                title: 'Log In',
                colour: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                onPressed: () async {
                  setState(() {
                    showSpinner = true;
                  });
                  try {
                    UserCredential userCredential = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
                  } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
                    if (e.code == 'user-not-found') {
                      print('No user found for that email.');
                    } else if (e.code == 'wrong-password') {
                      print('Wrong password provided for that user.');
                    }
                  }
                },
              ),
```

Everything here works but I want to display the error messages rather than put them in the console.  How do I do this?

Comment: check out this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56113778/how-to-handle-firebase-auth-exceptions-on-flutter

Comment: Thanks. I saw that post but I missed the snackbar answer.

Answer (score 0):

use another_flushbar package to display error on screen

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).