# How can i know all Possible wrong login

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, authentication, logging

**Flutter Dart**

i am using login by email and password but cannot distinguish what's kind of error with user login .. i mean how can i know if password or email the one who wrong , all what i can  do is when it is null so i can give wrong message for the users but cannot give him which part exactly the error from . if it was email or password ! or if the email was already in use .. how can i mange with this , thanks

```
ElevatedButton(
                            onPressed: () async {
                              if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                                try {
                                  var aa = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: _emailController.text, password: _passWordController.text);
                                  if (aa != null) {
                                    User yser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
                                    DocumentSnapshot doc = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").doc(yser.uid).get();
                                    if (mounted){
                                      setState(() {currentUser =  Yser.fromDocument(doc.data());});
                                    }
                                    Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, Pages.id);
                                  }
                                } catch (error) {
                                  print(error.toString());
                                  return null;
                                }
                              }
                            },
                          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom( minimumSize: Size(120,45) ),
                            child: Text("Login"),
                        ),
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Handle Firebase Auth exceptions on flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56113778/how-to-handle-firebase-auth-exceptions-on-flutter) Also checkout [FlutterFire Error Handling](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/error-handling/)

Comment: i have seen this , but it is old answer compare of latest firebase version ,

Comment: See [ask] to improve this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 login( String email, String password) async {
    try {
      return await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
       email: email, password: password);
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      if (e.code == 'user-not-found') {
        print('No user found for that email.');
        return ('No user found for that email.');
      } else if (e.code == 'wrong-password') {
        print('Wrong password provided for that user.');
        return ('Wrong password provided for that user.');
        
      }
    } catch (e) {
      return (e);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for this awesome answer , does it work for both platform ios and android ?

Comment: Yes, and web also.

Comment: you deserve it ..

Comment: can you please provide mw with the code if user already in use

Comment: `if (e.code == 'email-already-in-use')`

Comment: You're most welcome, happy coding! This is from the documentation btw, check it out, best place for firebase libraries.

Comment: sorry for being annoying . but also i need the code for wrong email

Comment: also if you provide me with direct link to that documentation will be thankful for you , i am still Beginner