# Wait till data in firestore has successfully updated

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to check if data is uploaded successfully to firestore when the user click the save button
and show toast or ask the user to try again if the document not update.

this is my code to update the document.

```
  Future updateTechnical(Technical technical) async {
    return await technicalsCollection.doc(technical.id).update({
      "name": technical.name,
      "address": technical.address,
      "phoneNum": technical.phoneNum,
      "tools": technical.tools,
    });
  }
```

And this is the save Button

```
       ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  DatabaseService().updateTechnical(
                    Technical(
                      id: selectedTechnical.id,
                      name: nameController.text,
                      address: addressController.text,
                      phoneNum: phoneController.text,
                      tools: selected.join(','),
                      
                    ),
                  );
                },
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Text('Save  '),
                    Icon(Icons.person_add),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
```

Comment: I suppose you are looking, WHEN firebase has been updated, right? You probably want to do something after you called `updateTechnical()` with the new data from firebase?!

Comment: yes, you are right, when firebase has been updated, I think this is will work. but what If I want to know **the reason why the document did not update** (like network connection, invalid data type,....etc)?

Comment: If the current answers are satisfying, please make sure to mark the most helpful one, so others can see the accepted one.

Answer (score 1):

To **wait till** the data has been successfully updated you can use `.then()`.

```
onPressed: () {
   DatabaseService().updateTechnical().then((value) => {
                         print("successfully uploaded!"),
                    });
},
```

To **check if any errors have occurred** during upload you should check in `updateTechnical()`:

```
 Future updateTechnical(Technical technical) async {
    try {
      final querySnapshot =
          await technicalsCollection.doc(technical.id).update({
        "name": technical.name,
        "address": technical.address,
        "phoneNum": technical.phoneNum,
        "tools": technical.tools,
      });
      return querySnapshot;
    } catch (error) {
      print(error); //here you can see the error messages from firebase
      throw 'failed';
    }
  }
```

If you need to do certain things, when a specific error occurs, you, unfortunately, have to check through all the error messages. Here is an example: [Handle exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56114582/11003497)

Answer (score 1):

To check if your data updated successfully, you'll want to catch any errors if they occur. I've modified your `updateTechnical()` function to do so here:

```dart
  Future updateTechnical(Technical technical) async {
    return await technicalsCollection.doc(technical.id).update({
      "name": technical.name,
      "address": technical.address,
      "phoneNum": technical.phoneNum,
      "tools": technical.tools,
    }).then((value) => print("Updated successfully")) // success toast here
          .catchError((error) => print("Failed to update: $error")); // fail toast here
  }
```

You could also use a try/catch block, but that is considered a little less efficient and is generally avoided where possible